# InvokeWebrequest says it can't connect to server, but a normal web browser works fine

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest, blacklist

I'm trying to write a better script for my RMM to install Cove Data Protection. I wanted to pass a filename because for silent install the file needs a specific filename so it conects properly. I have a variable for the output file to be the bm#xyz123abc456#.exe that it wants.

`Invoke-WebRequest 'https://cdn.cloudbackup.management/maxdownloads/mxb-windows-x86_x64.exe' -OutFile $coveFilename`

However, I get:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest 'https://cdn.cloudbackup.management/maxdownloads/mx ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

However, I can put that exact link into any web browser and it downloads the file no issue.

I was expecting it to download the file and write the file as the specific filename it needs. Web browser works perfectly, and manually renaming the file works perfectly. So why is powershell having an issue?

This is all machines, all locations, regardless of firewalls and such. All Windows Server 2022 or Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: I can use Invoke-WebRequest on other sites however. This is a plethora of machines, many untouched by any proxy settings. I don't even know where to begin to change a config file on 2900 computers in 500 different companies.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.... [ThreatLocker](https://www.threatlocker.com/why-threatlocker) ringfencing PowerShell!

Comment: Good to know. Since the problem was PowerShell-specific, a `curl.exe` workaround would probably have worked too: `curl.exe -L 'https://cdn.cloudbackup.management/maxdownloads/mxb-windows-x86_x64.exe' -o $coveFilename`